# Parsing complicated combinations of single and double quotes

Tags: php, jquery

I came across a line of jQuery that builds a link to put into a div:

```
$('div#viewSite').html("<a href='<?=$_SESSION['root_url'] ?>" + siteName + ".html' target='_blank'>View " + siteName +"</a>");
```

This works. If $_SESSION['root_url'] is "http://mainsite.com/" and siteName is "d3" then div#viewSite gets the link "view d3" and clicking the link goes to http://mainsite.com/d3.html.

But the quotes to make it work are a nightmare. The single quote after href= is matched by the single quote after .html, but each of these single quotes is in a different double quote span, which seems like it may or may not work, though, in fact, it does work.

Has anyone worked out an algorithm for breaking down and seeing  quotes correctly in complicated lines like this? Even Aptana is unable to correctly match up the quotes.

Thanks

Comment: Sublime Text 3 parses the line handily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you simply don't write a line of code that is that unreadable?  To me you could make this much better with something like:

```
var html = '<a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['root_url']; ?>' + siteName + '.html"' +
           ' target="_blank">View ' + siteName + '</a>';
$('div#viewSite').html(html);
```

Note use of long PHP tags which most editors do a better job with in terms of contextual highlighting.